# How to select option with a name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `<select>`:

```
<select id="to" name="contact">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option name="4307" value="">Nitheesh</option>
  <option name="4306" value="">Ramanatan</option>
</select>
```

When I pass a variable through `get`, which will be equal to one of the name, I want that particular `<option>` to selected.

Comment: you can set option value, not any name.

Comment: You can't use name You can use data attribute data-name

Comment: Why aren't you setting value on the options instead of using `name`?

Comment: And how far did you get, when you attempted this?

Comment: value attribute is already in use.

Comment: And the `name` attribute is invalid; use - as Rajesh suggested - a valid `data-*` custom attribute.

Comment: You can add the empy `selected` attribute to a option tag to choose which option is visible. Simply iterate through your options (or use a query selector), find the one with the appropriate name value and add it to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `filter` method in order to find out `option` which have your given `text`.

```js
var name="Nitheesh";
var option=$("select option").filter(function(i,option){
  return $(option).text()==name;
}).attr('selected','selected');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="to" name="contact">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option name="4307" value="Nitheesh">Nitheesh</option>
   <option name="4306" value="">Ramanatan</option>
</select>
```

If you want to obtain an option by particular `name` attribute, use this:

```
$("option[name = '" + name + "']").attr('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**Attribute Equal Selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) like this:

```
var someName = /*...*/;
var $option = $("[name = '" + someName + "']");
```

Here is a reference of other [**CSS Selectors**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks, worked with $("[name=<?php echo $_GET['enqNo']?>]").attr('selected', true);

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery can use an attribute selector

```js
var newVal = 4306;

$('#to option[name="' + newVal +'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="to" name="contact">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option name="4307" value="">Nitheesh</option>
   <option name="4306" value="">Ramanatan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //given get val
  var val = "4307";
  
  $("#to option[name="+val+"]").attr("selected",true);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="to" name="contact">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option name="4307" value="">Nitheesh</option>
   <option name="4306" value="">Ramanatan</option>
</select>
```